# how to print loop plotting into single pdf /multiple pdf files

Tags: r, pdf

I am doing loop ploting, and want to print plots into pdf. what should I do. I am very confused.

the looping codes looks like this:

```
for (i in 1:12)){

   df<-Sample.Data %>% filter(ID==i) 
         p1 <- ggplot(data =df)+
   geom_line(aes(x = Days, y = Result, color = Item))+
      
 print(p1)
 }
```

then, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `pdf` function (No data provided so it is not possible to add some output):

```
#Pdf
pdf('Example.pdf',width = 14)
#Loop
for (i in 1:12)){
  #Data
  df<-Sample.Data %>% filter(ID==i) 
  #Plot
  p1 <- ggplot(data =df)+
    geom_line(aes(x = Days, y = Result, color = Item))
  #Print
  plot(p1)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Can I define output location? if I defined my location as `outfile`, then how I can output pdf at that location with name 'test.pdf'?

Comment: @Stataq You have to set a directory with `setwd()` and then your pdf will be saved in that location.

Comment: I did not use setwd(), instead, I used `out_dir = "//Statistics"`

Comment: @Stataq In that case try this: `pdf(paste0(out_dir,'//Example.pdf'),width = 14)` at the beginning of the code!

Comment: Thanks so much! It works.